# Divide argv parameters and write in array

Tags: c, arrays, terminal, argv

Basically it's a sudoku puzzle, and we get the program running through the console

Every Argv parameter consists of 9 digits(a dot may replace a missing digit) that are written to a two-dimensional array like this:

```
./sudoku "9...7...." "2...9..53" ".6..124.." "84...1.9." "5.....8.." ".31..4..." "..37..68."
".9..5.741" "47......."
```

and the array values must be:

```
array[0][0] = 9, array[0][1] = 0, ..., array[8][0] = 4, ...
```

the main fragment:

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int s_f[9][9];
    int i;
    int j;

i = 1;
j = 0;
if (argc != 10)
    write(1, "Error\n", 6);
else
{
```

and there goes the code that i'm trying to use:

```
while (i < 10)
    {
        j = 0;
        while(j < 9)
        {
            s_f[i - 1][j] = write(1, &(argv[i][j]), 1);
            j++;
        }
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        i++;
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);
}
```

If there's zero instead of a digit in an argument, it should be replaced by a zero.

Any ideas on how to read the Argv parameters and put them to int, so it would be easier to proceed with finding solutions?

P.S. The only allowed functions are **write, malloc** and **free**.

P.P.S. Atoi is allowed.

Comment: like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zgoAoEbEwLeC63oy) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so the solution is

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int s_f[9][9];
    int i;
    int j;

i = 1;
j = 0;
if (argc != 10)
    write(1, "Error\n", 6);
else
{
    while (i < 10)
    {
        j = 0;
        while(j < 9)
        {
            if (ft_strcmp(&argv[i][j], ".") == 0)
                s_f[i - 1][j] = 0;
            else
                s_f[i - 1][j] = argv[i][j] - '0';
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < 9)
{
    while (j < 9)
    {
        if (s_f[i][j] == -2)
            s_f[i][j] = 0;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    j = 0;
}

i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < 9)
{
    while (j < 9)
    {
        if (j != 8)
            printf("%d ", s_f[i][j]);
        else
            printf("%d", s_f[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    j = 0;
    printf("\n");
}
return (0);
}
```